# Memoir odd page numbers are on the left?

Tags: memoir

I just noticed that my odd page numbers are on the left. How do I ensure they are on the right? E.g., my contents have the spine margin on the right.

EDIT

Umm... Never mind. @UlrikeFischer's comment below clued me in that my page is formatted correctly. I wrongly thought that the wider margin should be on the spine.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal document that replicates your current issue? That is, supply us with code so we can see where you might have some setting that causes the problem you're experiencing. Code should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Can you do that?

Comment: @Werner I updated my OP with a reduced piece of my code and the page it generates. Is it possible that my TeX caches need to be wiped so I can rebuild from scratch? Is that a thing? I'm a newb.

Comment: You realize that `\chapter` uses `\thispagestyle{plain}`?

Comment: You are showing a right page. The small  margin is the inner margin.

Comment: @JohnKormylo can you elaborate please? I don't know how `\thispagestyle{plain}` relates to my question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this right page but shouldn't the right page have the large margin on the left side of the page for the spine? Or am I missing something?

Comment: no, it shouldn't. That is a common misunderstanding, but the inner margin is smaller, as you have two inner margins which add up (from the left and right page). Look at page 30 of the memoir documentation.

Comment: \pagestyle{plain} puts the page number on the bottom center.  Not sure what memoir uses for its default pagestyle.